# Animate text to slide up and replace with another text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website where the data is dynamically changed. I wanted to show the data in an animated format like the text moves up and another text comes in its place from the bottom.

Like in this site http://www.moneycontrol.com/.

The way the stocks slides up and replaced by another. Are there any jquery plugins similar to this one or any way in which I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any jQuery plugins that can do this for you, but if you fancy a stab at it, this is what you would need:

1. Your old and new data set
2. Two elements (`div` or whatever) for *old* and *new* data display

Let's say element A is the one currently being displayed, and element B is the *next* that will slide in.

Place both in a container element `C`, with `overflow:hidden; position:relative` and animate them to slide up.

Once `A` is out of the view (top: <negative value>) and `B` is in view (top: 0), remove `A` and re-insert it after `B`, and continue the cycle.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add an example code with which I can get a better understanding, I get your idea but an example would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a slideUp() option that would work for a simple solution. Here is some sample code and a fiddle that illustrates a very basic version of what you had in mind.
https://jsfiddle.net/adrianopolis/ezzLgLhy/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slide-up-container">
    <div class="slide-up-item" id="el_one">
        Foo
    </div>
    <div  class="slide-up-item" id="el_two">
        Bar
    </div>
</div>

<a id="foo_bar" href="#">Replace Foo with Bar</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide-up-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.slide-up-item {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
#el_one {
    background: blue;
}
#el_two {
    background: red;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#foo_bar").click(function(){
    $("#el_one").slideUp();
});
```